# Why is Stack Overflow not using Adverts services like Google Adsense

Tags: discussion, advertising

Why SE not using advert services like google adsense, and selling ad space instead. Is that more profits?
It can use them along with ad space selling itself even(at least until it get customers for that space. I seldom see any other than its own).

I know company's revenue is more from Careers and Tags. Still it could be good option being at the top of index for any coding related search queries on google.

And even after 200rep, it is giving the option of reduced ads. I don't think it would be that problem to anyone till 200.(Even personally I myself is having no problem even after 200rep, SO is helping use for all free)

Comment: But seriously, I haven't seen any external ads at all till now not a single!. And I'm still 104rep only. No Adblocks either. Thus out of curiosity arose this point!

Comment: "The short version is that we have *standards*."   -- [Adam Lear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236425/why-wont-stack-exchange-show-google-adsense-ads#comment775074_236425)

Comment: They tried in the early days, it was not worth the effort.  https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1265072567 and https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/3110057803

Comment: Good link @HansPassant Worth reading

Comment: @Servy - That is incorrect, please see my answer below.

Comment: ["Our hand-selected ads, targetted to our audience, perform 50 times better than AdSense."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/podcast-64/)

Comment: StackOverflow probably doesn't want to be plastered with cheesy half-baked ads , is why. The way it is currently, is more dignified overall

Comment: Awesome read @BradLarson

Comment: And now they _are_ using Ads by Google. @BradLarson ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stack Exchange, Inc. has an internal sales team that handles the sales of banners on our sites, currently offering advertising on 16 sites: https://stackexchange.com/mediakit.

We do not work with ad networks such as Google AdSense, or sell our inventory at remnant rates just to make a buck.

We choose to work directly with reputable companies that are relevant to our audience and vet every ad that runs on our sites.

Bottom line is that if our users do not find the ads relevant, they will not click on them. If our audience doesn't click on our ads, we won't be able to sell them to advertisers.

Comment: Should also add @BradLardson comment also in your answer. :-)

Comment: @sachin Brad's answer references a podcast from 2009. Much has changed since then, including hiring an in-house ad sales team. While it has many philosophies that are still relevant today, I'd rather this post have the most up-to-date info.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Looks like I'm a little late to the game. Appears [this happened in 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301524/all-sites-will-be-switching-ad-servers-on-october-1).

---

**Now, in 2020, they do.**

I saw a particularly annoying advert (not animated, but a little more... mainstream looking?... than usual), clicked the `X` on it, and up it popped.

I mean, they're just trying to make a buck, bless their hearts, but...

> We do not work with ad networks such as Google AdSense, or sell our
> inventory at remnant rates just to make a buck.
>
> We choose to work directly with reputable companies that are relevant
> to our audience and vet every ad that runs on our sites.

... from Danny Miller is a dated answer now, if only in that they need to be more nuanced in the description of their partnership with Google Ads.

[image: Example of Ads by Google on a stackoverflow question]